# Select records that have any null value on the Jsonb column

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have a table with a JSONB column. How to select records that have any null value on the JSONB column? I searched for a while and can't find anything, all results I have need a special key for query, and because I have dynamic key-value, I can't use this method.

```json
abc
{"color": null, "size": "XL" }
{"name": "John", "Height": null, "weight": null }
```

Comment: That's an invalid JSON value. Is that inside an array? Or part of a larger JSON structure?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: they are sample data for column Abc of 2 records

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using a JSON path expression.

```
select *
from the_table
where jsonb_path_exists(the_column, '$.keyvalue() ? (@.value == null)')
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `jsonb_each_text`, sample data

```
select * into tbl 
from (
  values
     (1, '{"color": "blue", "size": "XL" }'::jsonb),
     (2, '{"name": "John", "Height": null, "weight": null }'::jsonb)
)t(id, val);
```

The query

```
select t.*
from tbl t
where exists (
   select 1 
   from jsonb_each_text(t.val) 
   where value is null
)
```