# How do I find all models with a jsonb object with any null values in the key/value pairs through Active Record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, jsonb

I have a model `User` with a jsonb column `email_triggers`.

Email triggers is a series of key value pairs structured like `{"email_one": "3/1/22", "email_two": "4/9/22", email_three: null}`

I want to find all users where at least one of those values is `null`

I've been trying to convert the jsonb object into an array of values and then ask if null is included in that array

`User.where("array[jsonb_each(email_triggers.value)] @> null")`

Which is compiling as

`SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE (array[jsonb_each(email_triggers.value)] @> null) ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $1`

but I am getting an undefined table error

`PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "email_triggers" (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid) LINE 1: ...CT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE (array[jsonb_each(email_trig...`

I'm not even sure this is the correct approach at this point, but the goal was to try to search against all values in the object to see if there are any null values.

Note: I also tried a_horse_with_no_name's suggested [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71635750/select-records-that-have-any-null-value-on-the-jsonb-column) and it didn't return the desired result

Comment: If you instead use a join table to store your email triggers, this is trivial. It will also enforce a proper date type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The proper [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) representation of null is `null` not `"nil"`.
- `email_triggers.value` means the column `value` of the table `email_triggers`.

You can use `jsonb_each` to turn the object into a table, join with it, find the values which are `null` (JSON null, not SQL null), and select only the distinct IDs.

```
select
  distinct id
from users, jsonb_each(email_triggers)
where value = 'null';
```

---

This can be made simpler if you store `email_triggers` as an array, and you might as well use a [standard date format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). For example: `["2022-03-01", "2022-04-09", null]`

Now it's a simple `@>` (contains) search.

```
Users.where("email_triggers @> 'null'")
```

---

Finally, this will be faster and work better with Rails as a normal join table.

You can enforce the dates be stored with the proper [`date` type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html) and converted into Ruby Date objects.

```
class User << ApplicationRecord do
  has_many :email_triggers
end

# create_table(:email_triggers) do |t|
#   belongs_to :user, foreign_key: true
#   t.date :trigger_at, null: false
# end
class EmailTrigger << ApplicationRecord do
  belongs_to :user
end
```

The search is now a simple join.

```
Users.join(:email_triggers).where(trigger_at: nil)
```

However, this search is now not needed if you disallow nulls.